# Using Yii2 Bootstrap widgets with Smarty

Tags: twitter-bootstrap-3, smarty, yii2

I've installed Yii2 together with Smarty for my views.

Smarty itself is working, but I can't figure out how to use the bootstrap widgets with smarty, nor find any examples.

With the default Yii renderer the widgets work great, and lots of examples are available. But when using Smarty templates documentation is nearly non existing.

How would I define this example with Smarty ?

```
echo Alert::widget([
   'options' => [
      'class' => 'alert-info',
   ],
   'body' => 'Alert widget',
]);
```

Obviously the first thing would be

```
{use class="yii\bootstrap\Alert"}
```

But I can't find an example of how to define the widget itself.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

After changing config/web.php and adding:

```
'globals' => ['html' => '\yii\helpers\Html'],
'uses' => ['yii\bootstrap'],
```

in the view section, it works.

```
{use class='yii\bootstrap\Alert' type='function'} 
{Alert body='Alert' options=['class' => 'alert-info']}
```

So without the @  soju suggested.

Answer (score 0):

You should simply try this :

```
{use class='@yii\bootstrap\Alert' type='function'}
{Alert body='Alert widget' options=['class' => 'alert-info']}
```

Read more : http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/guide-tutorial-template-engines.html#importing-static-classes-using-widgets-as-functions-and-blocks

Comment: Thanks. After changing config/web.php and adding 

  'globals' => ['html' => '\yii\helpers\Html'],
  'uses' => ['yii\bootstrap'],

in the view section, it works with:
{use class='yii\bootstrap\Alert' type='function'}